# Limit WordPress users to post one comment per post

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, comments

I need to limit WordPress registered users (not guests) to **only post one comment per each post**. For example every registered user can post 20 comments but on 20 different posts.

Then the form become hidden/removed for that specific user.

How do I edit the following code?

```
comment_form();
```

Comment: Maybe it will be helpfull, same problem.
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137799/how-to-limit-users-to-one-comment-per-post

Answer (score 2):

```
$is_commented = get_comments(array('user_id' => $current_user->ID, 'post_id'=>$post->ID) );
if($is_commented) {
    // give the user a message saying he already have commented
} else {
    comment_form();
}
```

Comment: Can I use $is_commented = true or something similar?

Comment: um...it returns a array of comment objects if the user has one or more comments for that post or an empty array if no comments. So, you can't use for Boolean operations.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have found your solution here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/one-comment-per-user-per-post

Seems pretty straight forward, though I'm still learning also. :)

Let me know if this worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach is to check whether a user has commented the post, or not. If they have commented the post, then disable comment form.

```
global $current_user;
$args = array('user_id' => $current_user->ID);
$usercomment = get_comments($args);
if(count($usercomment) >= 1){
    echo 'disabled';
} else {
    comment_form();
}
```

I tested my site and answered it. This method was very sure,
Site [https://digiwp.com](https://digiwp.com/)